# Why is a page starting with .. illegal?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page called ..hi i get this error when visiting the page. Why is that illegal?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.
Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of the [URI Specification](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#absolutize) (section 5.2, "relative resolution"), dots are always removed from the URI and used to specify relative paths.  The double-dot `..` refers to the parent path.

It's technically an invalid URI because these relative path tokens need to be followed by a path separator, i.e. the `/`.  In your case, it's being followed by the text `hi`, which doesn't conform to the specification and comes back as a "bad request."

Answer (score 2):

".." denotes "parent directory" when referencing a file.
"." denotes the current directory.

If you try to name it ..XXX, it assumes you're giving it a relative file path, and it looks in the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the file name `..`? Well the problem with that is that `..` refers to the parent directory which is a bad thing to access from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `..` is also the file name of the parent folder. The server is interpreting the request as the parent folder then `hi`.